How to add new sections of a formula for each new input in excel?
I am making a grid map that you can place specific source points into based on coordinates and I would like the formulas to automatically update for a much higher number of sources. If a cell is not a source, I would like the cell to read how far it is from each source added together. Right now I have nested IFs with XLOOKUPs to insert the first two sources into the grid, but adding another IF/XLOOKUP to check for each new source as well as run the calculation in the final FLASE output of the nested IFs would be too complicated for the end user. Some of these XLOOKUPs are not needed, but I thought they may help with automation of further expansion. I think something along the lines of a 'for each Sn in SnName, lookup its value in SnX, SnY, and SnZ and calculate a cells value based on the calculation in final FALSE output of nested IFs' may be what the solution is, but am hoping there is a more elegant solution only using formulas rather than macros. I would also like to keep it formula dependent so the grid may be easily expanded by the end user rather than editing macro code. I am open to reworking how the sheet is set up so far to better suit the end goal.
The current code in each of the grid cells is:

=IF(AND(XLOOKUP($AI$2,SnName,SnX)=COLUMN(B2)-1,XLOOKUP($AI$2,SnName,SnY)=ROW(B2)-1),$AI$2,IF(AND(XLOOKUP($AI$3,SnName,SnX)=COLUMN(B2)-1,XLOOKUP($AI$3,SnName,SnY)=ROW(B2)-1),$AI$3,
SQRT(SUMSQ(ABS(XLOOKUP($AI$2,SnName,SnX)-COLUMN(B2)),ABS(XLOOKUP($AI$2,SnName,SnY)-ROW(B2)),XLOOKUP($AI$2,SnName,SnZ)))
+SQRT(SUMSQ(ABS(XLOOKUP($AI$3,SnName,SnX)-COLUMN(B2)),ABS(XLOOKUP($AI$3,SnName,SnY)-ROW(B2)),XLOOKUP($AI$3,SnName,SnZ)))))



I'd say that you could create a name-based grid for each new source and use a formula to add them up. The given source could be set as an error in each grid so it would result in an error at the end of the sum.

Anyway: what kind of movement is allowed? I understand this is a cube. Using chess: can we move like towers or like queens? Assuming we can move like towers, the minimal distance between your should be 27, but i would expect cell L10 (x11y9) to be equal to cell K11 (x10y10). So why is it 28 and not 27? Each cell on the tracks of minimum distance should have a value of 27. Also shouldn't cell B2 (x1y1) have a higher value? 43 is equal to 17+23+3, just the minimum distance between x1y1z8 and x18y24z12; it's not considering source S1. Am i missing something?

A formula based approach might get really heavy quite hastly, so i would reccomend a VBA approach. Anyway, assuming we can "move like towers in chess", here is a possible formula based solution:



Sn
X
Y
Z
°°°Name°°°
=IFERROR((1/(ABS(COLUMN(INDIRECT("C1:C"&$I$1,FALSE))-INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("°°°Name°°°",$E:$E)))+ABS(ROW(INDIRECT("R1:R"&$I$2,FALSE))-INDEX($C:$C,MATCH("°°°Name°°°",$E:$E)))+ABS($I$4-INDEX($D:$D,MATCH("°°°Name°°°",$E:$E)))))^-1,-$I$1*$I$2*$I$3)

Width
25

=I4
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25

=I4
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25




S1
10
9
8
Source1
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT($F$1),$E$1,E2)

Height
25

1
=Source1+Source2+Source3

























1
=IF(L2<0,INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($E:$E)/($B:$B=AM$1)/($C:$C=$AL2)/($D:$D=$I$4),1)),L2)


























S2
18
24
12
Source2
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT($F$1),$E$1,E3)

Depth
25

2


























2



























S3
24
2
15
Source3
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT($F$1),$E$1,E4)

Level
8

3


























3





































4


























4





































5


























5





































6


























6





































7


























7





































8


























8





































9


























9





































10


























10





































11


























11





































12


























12





































13


























13





































14


























14





































15


























15





































16


























16





































17


























17





































18


























18





































19


























19





































20


























20





































21


























21





































22


























22





































23


























23





































24


























24





































25


























25




























Copy it in a new sheet. You'll need to create a name for each series. For this example use the names listed in column E. In column F you'll find the formulas you'll have to assign to each name. Be aware that the cells in column F returns the formulas you'll need as values. They just differ from the original formula (stored in cell F1) by their reference to the given series. Any extra source will need its name created accordingly along with all the other data (coordinates and number). You will also have to add it to the sum in cell L2. For example: adding Source4 in this example you'll have to change the formula in cell L2 to =Source1+Source2+Source3+Source4.
Once you've created the necessary names select the range L2:AJ26 with cell L2 active, press F2 and then Ctrl+Shif+Enter (since the formula in cell L2 is meant to be an array formula). After that you can copy the formula in cell AM2 into the range AM2:BK26.
After applying the proper conditional formatting, you should end up with something like this:

Since you are visualizing only a slice of the cube, you have to choose which one. You can do that by changing the level value in cell I4. If you want to change the size of your cube, you'll have to change the size of the ranges L2:AJ26 and AM2:BK26 accordingly while also specifing the new dimensions in the proper cell of the range I1:I3 (width is for x, height is for y and depth is for z).
Then again: this approach is heavy and any other formula based approach will be likely so. A VBA solution would likely be much better.
